# MS Access VBA - take form record out of edit mode to allow recordset operations

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm editing records on a form.   I then want to do a recordset operation on the entire recordset underlying the form.  The recordset operation then runs into the error "Error - Could not update; currently locked by another session on this machine"...clearly because a record is being edited.

Regardless of whether this is good practice or not, how might I use vba to get the application to cancel, ignore or complete the form editing operation so that the recordset operation can continue...or it just not possible, because the GUI cannot be "released" from within VBA (kind of like when Excel cells are being edited)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can occur quite often. The simple trick is to ensure that the current form record is not "dirty" or is not pending a update.

Thus you can go:

```
if me.dirty = True then me.Dirty = False

' now call your update routines etc.
```

Because those other routines may well update the screen/record you are viewing, then you can execute a me.Refresh to ensure that any changes are displayed.

The above will force the record write. In fact if I am in a form, and plan say to launch some popup form, or a form in the next "step" for the user, I also tend to force write the current form out - it is not only safer, but avoids the common "this record been changed by another user". In most cases, the other user is in fact your code.

So simply save the record with the above one line of code - this should eliminate this issue in general. Keep in mind that you can set a form to lock the whole table in the "data" tab of the forms property sheet, but that is unlikely your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is the form data-bound?  It doesn't sound like it.

```
Me!SomeField = ...
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
```

If your form has control bound to "SomeField", then the form will be updated automatically.

1) Update records using SQL code. For example, you have ID of record that should be updated in the form data set, so you can write something like:

```
Call CurrentDB.Execute( _
"UPDATE SomeTable SET SomeField = SomeValue WHERE SomeTableID = " & Me!SomeTableID, dbSeeChanges)
```

2) You can look at the Bookmark property - both Recordset and Form has this property, it describes the record position. So you can write something like this (not the best example, but can help you to get an idea):

```
Dim Rs as Recordset
Set Rs = Me.RecordsetClone 'make a reference copy of the form recordset
Rs.Bookmark = Me.Bookmark 'locate this recordset to the form current record
```